# Graal Javascript - thread safety

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, graalvm, graaljs

What is the recommended way to use Graal.js in a multi-threaded application (such as per servlet request)?  We are using Graal.js like this

```
jsContext = Context.newBuilder("js").allowAllAccess(true).build();
bindings = jsContext.getBindings("js");
jsContext.eval("js", jsCodeString);
```

Should we have a unique Context/binding for each executing thread. This can be accomplished through a pool of Context/Binding pairs or by using threadlocal.  Is this the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not access one `Context` from several threads at the same time. So, the solutions that you propose (a pool of `Context`s or thread-local `Context`s) are valid ways to do that.

`graalvm/graaljs` repository [contains](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/tree/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.test.threading/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/test/threading) some threading-related examples. You can see the usage of a thread-local `Context` there (in [ExecutorsTest](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.test.threading/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/test/threading/ExecutorsTest.java)).

FYI: There is a [blog-post](https://medium.com/graalvm/multi-threaded-java-javascript-language-interoperability-in-graalvm-2f19c1f9c37b) about multi-threading with Graal JavaScript that may clarify further questions that you may have.